# Intercept hibernate @NotNull validation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, notnull

I have an entity (E1) that has ManyToMany relation to another entity (E2). So basicly it has a list of those entities. That relation is annotated with @NotNull since I do not want to have E1 created with a empty list of E2. That works.

The problem is that by design (which I am not able to change) it is possible to delete E2 even if it is contained in E1, so it can happen that at the end I have E1 that does not contain E2, and I am not able to (soft)delete it since @NotNull annotation does not allow it (soft delete is just an update which sets deleted flag to true).

Is there a way to intercept this @NotNull validation in case of soft delete and just say "hey hibernate it's ok, we can allow this to happen its beeing deleted".

Comment: What do you mean `@NotNull` doesn't allow soft deletes? It has nothing to do with soft deletes.

Comment: When I try to soft delete (update) E1 and it has null instead of list of E2s, it will fail since @NotNull does not allow it.

Comment: Then you might want to remove the `@NotNull` altogether, as it's not working correctly anyway.

Comment: Yes, I agree, I think there is no way to achieve what was asked in the question.

Comment: Probably not in any clean way that wouldn't introduce further instability in the system.

Comment: When you delete E2 (also soft delete but it does not matter), list in E1 gets updated (1 element of type E2 is removed from it), and so on until you have no E2s left, then the list in E1 is null. It is not directly in E1 table there is a table in between so E1 did not actually get updated but if you fetch it from DB you can see that the list is null. And then when you try to update E1 (soft delete it) you cant since the list is null. I solved it by just removing the annotation.